# My menu burger with javascript isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I have no Idea why its not working, hope you guys can give me a hand on my problem. I've double-checked the links and it appears to be okay, maybe it is an outdated code? Im stuck at this for two days and I cant figure out what's wrong with my js or the codes.

THE CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    body{
        overflow: hidden; /*Scroll OFF*/
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
         right: 0px;
         height: 92vh; /*Full screen*/
        
        /*direcionando para dentro da "barrinha"*/
        top: 8vh; 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;        

        background-color: rgb(1, 66, 44);
        
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
}

}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

The JS:

```
    const navSlide = ()=>{
        const burger = document.querySelector('.buger');
        const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

        burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });
}
navSlide();

    /*Multiple functions goes
const app = ()=> {
    navSlide();
    navSlide();
    navSlide();  ....}*/
```

Comment: just for you guys know, My html is okay, everything was showing up but the js no. 

I put this at the end but it did not helped so I don't think its a link problem. 

``` <script src = "/scripts/main.js" > </script>```

Comment: Please define "_it's not working_". What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have
const navSlide = ()=>{
const burger = document.querySelector('.buger');

your need
const navSlide = ()=>{
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');

you spelled the selector incorrectly'

also if you use bootstrap you could achieve this with only html classes and css.

Comment: Thanks dude, It did worked, I really have spelled BURGER WRONG

Im kinda new at this so I dont know how to do with bootstrap, Im just trying to do something more interesting for my college haha

Comment: so do a quick guide on bootstrap. There is a Udemy course by Dr. Angela Yu that is basically a software engineer boot camp. her section on bootstrap teaches how to make a burger menu. if you get it when Udemy has a sale its only 11$. It is very worth it.

Comment: I would be happy if I have the money to do it, dollars = 6R$ here So I need 66 R$ to pay it :c